# UML class diagrams in Java

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

I want to make a UML class diagram. By hand, not generated from code. The problem: UML is a very broad specification - I can't map all Java features to how they should look like in the diagram. There are associations, dependencies, aggregations, compositions. They are all well-documented, but not specifically for Java, so:

- When should I use which type of connection?
- How to handle inner classes (static or not)?
- What about static, final, abstract methods/fields? I think I must make it bold/italic/underlined, but how do I map those together?
- Abstract classes, Final classes, Enums?

Answer (score 2):

1. too broad. Try asking for a specific application.
2. Just nest them.
3. Use according stereotypes.
4. Abstract classes are shown with name in italics. Use stereotype for `<<final>>`. There's a `<<enumeration>>` meta type.

Answer (score 1):

I use draw.io when I need to make the UML and/or other diagrams. Everything there is manual, you just drag the design and then write the fields,functions, class, etc.

If you don't know when to use connections, classes, etc then go back to learning then try again once you know good enough.